# Reference for the category of functors from finite sets with surjections to abelian groups

Tags: homotopy-theory, abelian-categories, functors

In the talk of Jacob Lurie  about Lie Algebras and Homotopy theory, he mention at the end about a category of functors that has the same derived category as the category as some category of universal Lie algebras.

I found a reference of the universal Lie Algebra, in the paper "The universal Lie algebra" of  P. Vogel, but I cannot find a reference of this category of functors.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LeaiPHAh0X0&t=1s